# xslt resolve hierarchy and copy into new document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<nodes>
<node id="123">
   <elemref id="1"/>
   <elemref id="2"/>
   <noderef id="222"/>
</node>
<node id="456">
   <elemref id="4">
      <elemref id="2828"/>
   </elemref>
   <elemref id="5"/>
   <noderef id="444"/>
</node>
<node id="222">
   <elemref id="6"/>
   <elemref id="8"/>
   <noderef id="666"/>
</node>
<node id="444">
   <elemref id="11"/>
   <elemref id="22"/>
   <noderef id="888"/>
</node>
</nodes>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<nodes>
<node id="123">
   <elemref id="1"/>
   <elemref id="2"/>
   <subnode id="222">
       <elemref id="6"/>
       <elemref id="8"/>
   <!-- resolve noderef 666 -->
   </subnode>  
</node>
<node id="456">
   <elemref id="4">
      <elemref id="2828"/>
   </elemref>
   <elemref id="5"/>
   <subnode id="444">
       <elemref id="11"/>
       <elemref id="22"/>
       <!-- resolve noderef 888 -->
   </subnode>
</node>
</nodes>
```

So basically I need to resolve all the noderefs. The nodes that they refer to are in the same document (nodes 666 and 888 are ommitted here for bervity). I need a document that correctly displays the hierarchy of nodes and elemrefs. Everything can be nested arbitrarily deep.

So each node can have an unknown number of elemrefs that could each contain a variable amount of elemrefs and noderefs which in turn contain elemrefs and so forth.

I'd be very thankful for any tips and help! Working with XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, it should be quite easy to do using [keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key):

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="node-by-id" match="node" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="noderef-by-id" match="noderef" use="@id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- only unreferenced nodes are ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="/nodes">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node[not(key('noderef-by-id', @id))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- resolve references -->
<xsl:template match="noderef">
    <subnode id="{@id}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('node-by-id', @id)/*"/>
   </subnode>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hopefully, you don't have any circular references.

Comment: It seemed to have worked :D  a big THANK YOU You wouldnt happen to have time to explain how it works? The first template copies everything as is, the second template selects all nodes that dont have a noderef element with the same id and the last one selects all noderefs and replaces them with <subnode> and then just selects all child nodes as-are? what exactly does the key() return so that you can just go not(key())? I dont get how the copy-element works, really. Why do you use copy and then apply-templates inside? what would be different if it had circular references? Would it just not work?

Comment: 1. `xsl-copy` does a "shallow copy": it copies the element, but not it's contents. -- 2. the key() function returns a set of nodes that match the key value; the predicate `[not(key(...)]` selects only nodes that do not have a corresponding node matched by the key value. -- 3. A circular reference would send your processor into an infinite loop.